# Codename One add component to container

Tags: java, codenameone

I have created a form and added a container. 
I am trying to add a component to the container by using this code

```
    Component container = new Container(new GridBagLayout());        
    try{        
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = 2;
        c.weightx = 0.2d;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        container.addComponent((Object) c, new Label("My Label"));
        ....
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }
```

However when use this code I get this error ...

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   method addComponent(Object,Component)
location: variable container of type Component
```

I have followed all the instructions on the website but I cannot seem to add this component

Thanks

Comment: can you post link to website ?

Comment: Website: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Container.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No try but I think that

```
Component container = new Container(new GridBagLayout());
```

should be replaced by :

```
Container container = new Container(new GridBagLayout());
```

since `addComponent()` is not a method of `Component` but of `Container`.
You can see that in the javadoc :

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Container.html

Comment: Oh sheesh of course - doh! That worked. Thank you. So obvious.